# ¿Cómo subir un archivo con varios JS y HTML para formular una pregunta?

Tags: soporte, preguntas

Mi código no funciona sin el resto de JS. En total, tengo 4 ficheros JS y 4 HTML.

¿Cómo puedo subir varios archivos al realizar mi pregunta?

Comment: No queda claro lo que estás preguntando. Podrías contarnos dónde quieres subirlos. ¿Un servidor remoto? Para eso puedes usar FTP en todas sus variantes, `rsync`, un `git hook` y automatizar eso usando por ejemplo `fabric`

Comment: aqui, quiero no solo subir un html css y js que es lo que permite SO, sino 4

Comment: Puedes unificar todos los js en uno solo o pegarnos las partes relevantes, no subas todo tu proyecto entero, solo la parte que te da problemas.

Comment: esque desde un html abro otro por lo que uso window.opener todo el tiempo, si no subo todos no funcionara

Comment: Francisco por favor aclara la pregunta. Entiendo por tu comentario que te refieres a subir el codigo a los snippets de las preguntas de SOes...

Comment: @franciscodwq creo que deberías seguir el cosejo de esa pregunta duplicada. De lo contrario, es muy poco probable que alguien vaya a evaluar una pared de código antes de responderte. Agrego que si te estás refiriendo a bibliotecas externas como jQuery o Bootstrap, se pueden agregar con la etiqueta `<script>` dentro del HTML, de la misma forma que como [te editaron algunas publicaciones](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/141885/revisions).